# Replacing Django auth app and middleware with custom auth app and authentication middleware

Tags: django, session, authentication, django-middleware

After researching on ways to extend user table of auth app in django , I have decided to write my own auth app.
These are the things which I need to do for replacing the `contrib.auth` app:

1. Create an `AuthenticationMiddleware` class and add an `MyAuth.models.User` object in every request instead of `django.auth.models.User` and point to it in settings file.
2. Create a custom `AuthenticationBackend`.
3. Create `AuthenticationContextProcessor`s and similarly point to them in settings file.

Questions:

1. Do I need to do any editing in any other app or session middleware class?
2. The basic reason of writing my own auth app is not having enough fields in the user table 
         and I don't like the idea of `user_profile`. I have noticed that we add user 
         object to every request so that I can use that in sessions.
         But If I add more fields in user table then user object will get bigger 
         and if added to every request will only increase the load. 
         Am I right? Will increasing the size of the user object pose any load problems? Or will the effect be negligible?

Comment: What exactly, do you not like about user_profile? It isn't perfect, but at least for me, it works well enough (compared to the pain of re-writing a whole *auth* app).

Comment: Maintaining user data in two tables and extra joins. I have to put manytomany field in other table instead of user table which does not feel right. But all this is my opinion so no point in discussing it.
My question is are there any pitfalls in my scheme mentioned above besides taking the pain of writing an app again?

Comment: don't forget to include [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/) in your custom middleware ;)